# No GPU activities in profiling with nvprof

Tags: c++, c, cuda, nvidia, nvprof

I run `nvprof.exe` on the function that initialize data, calls three kernels and free's data. All profiled as it should and I got result like this:

```
==7956== Profiling application: .\a.exe
==7956== Profiling result:
 GPU activities:   52.34%  25.375us         1  25.375us  25.375us  25.375us  th_single_row_add(float*, float*, float*)                                   
                   43.57%  21.120us         1  21.120us  21.120us  21.120us  th_single_col_add(float*, float*, float*)                                       
                    4.09%  1.9840us         1  1.9840us  1.9840us  1.9840us  th_single_elem_add(float*, float*, float*)                        
      API calls:   86.77%  238.31ms         9  26.479ms  14.600us  210.39ms  cudaMallocManaged
                   12.24%  33.621ms         1  33.621ms  33.621ms  33.621ms  cuDevicePrimaryCtxRelease
                    0.27%  730.80us         3  243.60us  242.10us  245.60us  cudaLaunchKernel
                    0.15%  406.90us         3  135.63us  65.400us  170.80us  cudaDeviceSynchronize
                    0.08%  229.70us        97  2.3680us     100ns  112.10us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
                    0.08%  206.60us         1  206.60us  206.60us  206.60us  cuModuleUnload
                    0.01%  19.700us         1  19.700us  19.700us  19.700us  cuDeviceTotalMem
                    0.00%  6.8000us         1  6.8000us  6.8000us  6.8000us  cuDeviceGetPCIBusId
                    0.00%  1.9000us         2     950ns     400ns  1.5000us  cuDeviceGet
                    0.00%  1.8000us         3     600ns     400ns     800ns  cuDeviceGetCount
                    0.00%     700ns         1     700ns     700ns     700ns  cuDeviceGetName
                    0.00%     200ns         1     200ns     200ns     200ns  cuDeviceGetUuid
                    0.00%     200ns         1     200ns     200ns     200ns  cuDeviceGetLuid

==7956== Unified Memory profiling result:
Device "GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER (0)"
   Count  Avg Size  Min Size  Max Size  Total Size  Total Time  Name
      18  20.000KB  8.0000KB  32.000KB  360.0000KB  300.7000us  Host To Device
      24  20.000KB  8.0000KB  32.000KB  480.0000KB  2.647400ms  Device To Host
```

As you see there are three kernel in `GPU activities`.
And here is source code:

```
void add_elem(int n) {
  float *a, *b, *c1, *c2, *c3;
  cudaMallocManaged(&a, n * n * sizeof(float));
  cudaMallocManaged(&b, n * n * sizeof(float));
  cudaMallocManaged(&c1, n * n * sizeof(float));
  cudaMallocManaged(&c2, n * n * sizeof(float));
  cudaMallocManaged(&c3, n * n * sizeof(float));

  for (int i = 0; i < n*n; i++) {
    a[i] = 1.0f;
    b[i] = 2.0f;
    c1[i] = 0.0f;
    c2[i] = 0.0f;
    c3[i] = 0.0f;
  }

  int blockSize = 256;
  int numBlocks = (n*n + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
  th_single_elem_add<<<numBlocks, blockSize>>>(a, b, c1);
  th_single_row_add<<<numBlocks, blockSize>>>(a, b, c2);
  th_single_col_add<<<numBlocks, blockSize>>>(a, b, c3);

  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  cudaFree(a);
  cudaFree(b);
  cudaFree(c1);
  cudaFree(c2);
  cudaFree(c3);
}
```

After that, I extract initializing data, kernel call and freeing data to separate host functions and call `nvprof` again. In result I got only info about API calls, like this:

```
==18460== Profiling application: .\a.exe
==18460== Profiling result:
            Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
      API calls:   81.86%  158.78ms         9  17.643ms  1.4000us  158.76ms  cudaMallocManaged
                    0.17%  322.80us        97  3.3270us     100ns  158.00us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
                    0.11%  214.50us         1  214.50us  214.50us  214.50us  cuModuleUnload
                    0.04%  68.600us         3  22.866us  7.3000us  39.400us  cudaDeviceSynchronize
                    0.01%  12.100us         9  1.3440us     400ns  7.9000us  cudaFree
                    0.00%  7.7000us         1  7.7000us  7.7000us  7.7000us  cuDeviceGetPCIBusId
                    0.00%  2.1000us         3     700ns     300ns  1.0000us  cuDeviceGetCount
                    0.00%  2.0000us         2  1.0000us     300ns  1.7000us  cuDeviceGet
                    0.00%  1.2000us         3     400ns     300ns     500ns  cudaLaunchKernel
                    0.00%     700ns         1     700ns     700ns     700ns  cuDeviceGetName
                    0.00%     300ns         1     300ns     300ns     300ns  cuDeviceGetUuid
                    0.00%     300ns         1     300ns     300ns     300ns  cuDeviceGetLuid
```

As You see, also there is no section `Unified Memory profiling result`,
so I tried to run nvprof like this `nvprof.exe --unified-memory-profiling off .\a.exe` but got same result.
Source code for that:

```
void add_elem(int n) {
  float *a, *b, *c1;
  cudaMallocManaged(&a, n * n * sizeof(float));
  cudaMallocManaged(&b, n * n * sizeof(float));
  cudaMallocManaged(&c1, n * n * sizeof(float));

  for (int i = 0; i < n*n; i++) {
    a[i] = 1.0f;
    b[i] = 2.0f;
    c1[i] = 0.0f;
  }

  int blockSize = 256;
  int numBlocks = (n*n + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
  th_single_elem_add<<<numBlocks, blockSize>>>(a, b, c1);

  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  cudaFree(a);
  cudaFree(b);
  cudaFree(c1);
}

void add_row(int n) {
  float *a, *b, *c1;
  cudaMallocManaged(&a, n * n * sizeof(float));
  cudaMallocManaged(&b, n * n * sizeof(float));
  cudaMallocManaged(&c1, n * n * sizeof(float));

  for (int i = 0; i < n*n; i++) {
    a[i] = 1.0f;
    b[i] = 2.0f;
    c1[i] = 0.0f;
  }

  int blockSize = 256;
  int numBlocks = (n + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
  th_single_row_add<<<numBlocks, blockSize>>>(a, b, c1, n);

  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  cudaFree(a);
  cudaFree(b);
  cudaFree(c1);
}

void add_col(int n) {
  float *a, *b, *c1;
  cudaMallocManaged(&a, n * n * sizeof(float));
  cudaMallocManaged(&b, n * n * sizeof(float));
  cudaMallocManaged(&c1, n * n * sizeof(float));

  for (int i = 0; i < n*n; i++) {
    a[i] = 1.0f;
    b[i] = 2.0f;
    c1[i] = 0.0f;
  }

  int blockSize = 256;
  int numBlocks = (n + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
  th_single_col_add<<<numBlocks, blockSize>>>(a, b, c1, n);

  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  cudaFree(a);
  cudaFree(b);
  cudaFree(c1);
}
```

UPDATE:
I found the problem, I run code with 10000000000 elements in the array, and it seems like kernels not even called. Because I run them with 10000000 (10^8) elements and it took nearly 3 seconds to finish and with 10000000000 (10^10) it finished immediately. But there is no error oh anything.

How I should catch such cases?

Comment: start with [proper CUDA error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) and run your codes with `cuda-memcheck`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason here is kernels are called with unsupported `<<<numBlocks, blockSize>>>`.
After adding `gpuErrchk( cudaPeekAtLastError() );` after each kernel call, I got `GPUassert: invalid configuration argument`, that means I got unsupported with my GPU `numBlocks` or `blockSize` params. Without error checking script just ends silently.
As Robber Corvella suggested in a comment here is propper error handling link:

[proper CUDA error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api)

also, running `cuda-memcheck` helps